# Order date by day of the week

Tags: sql, oracle, date, sql-order-by

I'm an SQL rookie and trying to figure out how to display dates in a column as the day, and then order by day of the week (i.e. Monday > Tuesday > Wednesday > etc...)

Have the first part down (displaying as the day) but when I order by my 'DAY' column it seems to order alphabetically (i.e. Monday > Friday > Saturday > etc...)

Here is my query:

```
SELECT last_name, hire_date, TO_CHAR(hire_date, 'DAY') AS Day
FROM employees
ORDER BY Day
```

Any input would be much appreciated :)

Comment: use `ctrl-K` to format text as `code` or add 4 spaces at beginning of each line.

Comment: use `order by hire_date`

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I think he tag iSQL not sure what is that

Comment: Apologies, have updated now (Oracel SQL*Plus)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `to_char(<date>, 'd')` for the day of the week:

```
SELECT last_name, hire_date, TO_CHAR(hire_date, 'DAY') AS Day
FROM employees
ORDER BY TO_CHAR(hire_date, 'D');
```

There might be some additional manipulation to get the proper first day, because that depends on internationalization settings.

Comment: Thanks, worked a treat. Didn't realise I could apply character conversion with the order by keyword, nice to know.

Answer (score 1):

As vkp say you probably want

```
SELECT last_name, hire_date, TO_CHAR(hire_date, 'DAY') AS Day
FROM employees
ORDER BY hire_date
```

that will show days like

```
1/10/2015   thursday
2/10/2015   friday
...
30/10/2015  friday
```

but if you want order by day of the week not alphabetical you need use a date function different depend on your database

In **sql server** you have datepart

```
 select datename(dw,getdate()) --Friday       
 select datepart(dw,getdate()) --6
```

**Oracle** you have

```
select to_char(hire_date, 'D') from dual;
```

so  `order by to_char(hire_date, 'D')` will give you

```
05/10/2015   monday
12/10/2015   monday
19/10/2015   monday
26/10/2015   monday
06/10/2015   tuesday
13/10/2015   tuesday
20/10/2015   tuesday
27/10/2015   tuesday
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes I wanted to order as specified in your second example. I tried the order by 'datepart' as suggested but didn't seem to work, maybe not an Oracle compatible function?

Comment: Yes. I wrote that one when didnt know your rdbms, now I edit the answer to include an oracle function.

Comment: Thank you. Will be more specific woth database type in future questions!

Comment: No problem. You can read here to get tips of how ask better questions. [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
   And [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For example I answer two questions because wasnt sure what were you asking. So some sample data also help a lot.